# Winning team (classes)

Tags: python

Complete the Team class implementation. For the instance method get_win_percentage(), the formula is:
team_wins / (team_wins + team_losses)

Note: Use floating-point division.

Ex: If the input is:

Ravens
13
3
where Ravens is the team's name, 13 is the number of team wins, and 3 is the number of team losses, the output is:

Congratulations, Team Ravens has a winning average!
If the input is Angels 80 82, the output is:

Team Angels has a losing average.

My code is getting an attribute error:

```
class Team:
def __init__(self):
    self.team_name = 'none'
    self.team_wins = 0
    self.team_losses = 0
    
    def get_win_percentage(self):
        return self.team_wins / (self.team_wins + self.team_losses)


if __name__ == "__main__":

team = Team()

team_name = input()
team_wins = int(input())
team_losses = int(input())

team.team_name = team_name
team.team_wins = team_wins
team.team_losses = team_losses

if team.get_win_percentage() >= 0.5:
    print('Congratulations, Team', team.team_name,'has a winning average!')
else:
    print('Team', team.team_name, 'has a losing average.')
```

Comment: Getting an attribute error: 'Team' object has no attribute 'get_win_percentage'

Comment: I fixed the indentation and tried the code. It works!

Comment: @JohnColeman There are several problems with the indentation but most of them could have been caused by copying/pasting code into SO. The one that matters (IMO) is, as you said, the definition of `get_win_percentage` inside `__init__`.

Comment: Just a comment on the problem setting - if there is exactly the same number of wins and losses, I don't think that is either a winning or losing average.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation is wrong. Change to this:

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self):
        self.team_name = 'none'
        self.team_wins = 0
        self.team_losses = 0
        
    def get_win_percentage(self):
        return self.team_wins / (self.team_wins + self.team_losses)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    team = Team()
      
    team_name = input()
    team_wins = int(input())
    team_losses = int(input())
    
    team.team_name = team_name
    team.team_wins = team_wins
    team.team_losses = team_losses
    
    if team.get_win_percentage() >= 0.5:
        print('Congratulations, Team', team.team_name,'has a winning average!')
    else:
        print('Team', team.team_name, 'has a losing average.')
```

Test:

```
❯ python test.py
Masters
13
3
Congratulations, Team Masters has a winning average!
```